# reading files and saving them

Tags: python, dataframe

I am very new to Python and I a question regarding to read files and save them as a data.

Here is my problem:

1. These are the paths of all the data was saved:

   ```
   ./dataset/000**1**-SHC/exam000**1**.csv
   ./dataset/000**1**-SHC/exercise000**1**.csv
   ./dataset/000**1**-SHC/sleep000**1**.csv
   ```

   (10 folders with 3 files of exam and exercise and sleep.
2. Need to save every data in a single dataframe by changing the number 1.

   ```
   data-000**1**-exam="./dataset/000**1**-SHC/exam000**1**.csv"
   data-000**1**-sleep="./dataset/000**1**-SHC/exam000**1**.csv"
   data-000**1**-exercise="./dataset/000**1**-SHC/exam000**1**.csv"
   ```

I would appreciate it if someone could help me.

Comment: Surely you have given this a good effort yourself right? If so, please do share the code you have accomplished yourself and explain what difficulties you are having right now.

Comment: My code does not work. I have just tried for loop with errors.

Comment: Then please prove to us that you tried code by showing us your code. That helps us understand your level of understanding of Python and programming in general and proves that you are not one of the lazy ones who simply want us to do their homework.

Comment: Oh My God, I am also new here! I do not to show my silliest code right now. I will do my best to find a solution not a final code of others.